# Chrome DevTools Protocol - ContinueInterceptedRequest with gzip body in Golang

Tags: google-chrome, go, google-chrome-devtools, gzip

I have been working on a golang script that uses the [chrome devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to:

1) Intercept a request

2) Grab the response body for the intercepted request

3) Make some modifications to the `html` document

4) Continue the intercepted request

The script works for HTML documents except when `Content-Encoding` is set to `gzip`. The step-by-step process looks like this"

**1) Intercept Request**

```
 s.Debugger.CallbackEvent("Network.requestIntercepted", func(params godet.Params) {
    iid := params.String("interceptionId")
    rtype := params.String("resourceType")
    reason := responses[rtype]
    headers := getHeadersString(params["responseHeaders"])

    log.Println("[+] Request intercepted for", iid, rtype, params.Map("request")["url"])
    if reason != "" {
        log.Println("  abort with reason", reason)
    }

    // Alter HTML in request response
    if s.Options.AlterDocument && rtype == "Document" && iid != "" {
        res, err := s.Debugger.GetResponseBodyForInterception(iid)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("[-] Unable to get intercepted response body!")
        }

        rawAlteredResponse, err := AlterDocument(res, headers)
        if err != nil{
            log.Println("[-] Unable to alter HTML")
        }

        if rawAlteredResponse != "" {
            log.Println("[+] Sending modified body")

            err := s.Debugger.ContinueInterceptedRequest(iid, godet.ErrorReason(reason), rawAlteredResponse, "", "", "", nil)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("OH NOES AN ERROR!")
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }
    } else {
        s.Debugger.ContinueInterceptedRequest(iid, godet.ErrorReason(reason), "", "", "", "", nil)
    }
})
```

**2) Alter the response body**

Here I am making small changes to the HTML markup in `procesHtml()` (but the code for that function is not relevant to this issue, so will not post it here). I also grab headers from the request and when necessary update the `content-length` and `date` before continue the reponse. Then, I gzip compress the body when calling `r := gZipCompress([]byte(alteredBody)`, which returns a string. The string is then concatenated to the headers so I can craft the `rawResponse`.

```
func AlterDocument(debuggerResponse []byte, headers map[string]string) (string, error) {
    alteredBody, err := processHtml(debuggerResponse)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }


    alteredHeader := ""
    for k, v := range headers{
        switch strings.ToLower(k) {
            case "content-length":
                v = strconv.Itoa(len(alteredBody))
                fmt.Println("Updating content-length to: " + strconv.Itoa(len(alteredBody)))
                break
            case "date":
                v = fmt.Sprintf("%s", time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
                break
        }
        alteredHeader += k + ": " + v + "\r\n"
    }

    r := gZipCompress([]byte(alteredBody))

    rawAlteredResponse := 
    base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + "\r\n" + alteredHeader + "\r\n\r\n\r\n" + r))

    return rawAlteredResponse, nil
}
```

**Note**: I am now gzip compressing the body for all responses. The above is temporary while I figure out how to solve this issue.

The gzip compress function looks like this:

```
func gZipCompress(dataToWorkWith []byte) string{
    var b bytes.Buffer

    gz, err := gzip.NewWriterLevel(&b, 5)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    if _, err := gz.Write(dataToWorkWith); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := gz.Flush(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := gz.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

As seen in the first code snippet, the response body and headers are set here:

```
err := s.Debugger.ContinueInterceptedRequest(iid, godet.ErrorReason(reason), rawAlteredResponse, "", "", "", nil)
```

The result is a bunch of garbled characters in the browser. This works without the gzip functions for non gzipped requests. I have changed the compression level as well (without success). Am I processing the body in the wrong order (string > []byte > gzip > string > base64)? Should this be done in a different order to work? Any help would be immensely appreciated.

The response looks like this, which Chrome puts inside a `<body></body>` tag

����rܸ� ��_A��Q%GH��Kʔ��vU�˷c�v�}

or in the response:

[image: response screenshot]

I can also tell that it is compressing correctly as, when I remove headers, the request results in a `.gz` file download with all the correct `.html` when uncompressed. Additionally, the first few bytes in the object returned in `gZipCompress` tell me that it is gzipped correctly:

31 139 8

or

0x1f 0x8B 0x08

Comment: Shouldn't you first unzip the `debuggerResponse` when processing a gzipped request? What does your garbage look like? First few characters should be enough. From what I can see in your code looks like you might zip the already zipped content, which the browser only unzips once, thus the garbage.

Comment: `debuggerResponse` is already uncompressed. I should have noted that `processHtml` turns the byte array to a string by just doing `bodyString := string(body[:])`, at which point I create a `goquery` document and essentially do find/replace for a few strings. `processHtml` returns a string with the updated html. I will update the post with a sample of the response. Thank you

Comment: Also, note that `s.Debugger.GetResponseBodyForInterception` base64 decodes the response body when necessary before it is returned by that function.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate here, but will the resulting software be usable given the recent changes to Chrome's restrictions? I'm not 100% sure if this is related, but in recent versions of Chrome, applications such as anti-virus/malware are no longer able to hook into chrome's internals, as the browser no longer allows it. This seems to be an actual exposed API though, so at first glance it seems it will be fine, but I just noted that the stable V1.3 of this protocol is tagged at Chrome 64. Just something to look into to make sure you aren't wasting your time. Sorry for lacking resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a different library that handles larger responses better and more efficiently.

Now, it appears that the DevTools protocol returns the response body after decompression but before rendering it in the browser when calling `Network.GetResponseBodyForInterception`. This is an assumption only of course, as I do not see code for that method in https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol. The assumption is based on the fact that, when calling `Network.GetResponseBodyForInterception` the response body obtained is NOT compressed (though it may be base64 encoded). Furthermore, the method is marked as experimental and the documentation does not mention anything in regards to compressed responses. Based on that assumption, I will further assume that, at the point that we get the response from `Network.GetResponseBodyForInterception` it is too late to compress the body ourselves. I confirm that the libraries that I am working with do not bother to compress or uncompress gzipped responses.

I am able to continue working with my code without a need to worry about gzip compressed responses, as I can alter the body without problems.

For reference, I am now using https://github.com/wirepair/gcd, as it is more robust and stable when intercepting larger responses.